# Getting key value from key of hazelcast IMap

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I put my object to hazelcast map using spring annotation:

```
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName", key = "{ #someId1,#someId2}")

public String generateValue(Long someId1, Long someId2)
```

I would like to invalidate object from cache based on condition placed on key of the Imap. I found that key is a ArrayList with size equal 2. That is expected result.

```
 Set set = cache.keySet(); // this returns Set<ArrayList<Long>>
```

I try to set condition on key:

```
EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
Predicate predicateKey = e.key().get("__key#get(0)").equal(someId1).and(e.get("__key#get(1)").equal(someId2));
```

But invoking this predicate end up in failure:

```
Set<Long> idKeysToInvalidate = cache.keySet(predicateKey);

com.hazelcast.query.QueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for '__key#get(0)' on class 'class java.util.ArrayList'
at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.ReflectionHelper.createGetter(ReflectionHelper.java:176)
```

Did anyone encounter the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue as below:

```
    EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
    List<Long> input = Arrays.asList(someId1, someId2);
    Predicate predicateKey = e.key().get("hashCode").equal(input.hashCode());
    Set<List> idKeysToInvalidate = cache.keySet(predicateKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself, at least on a key, but can you try `__key#[0]` otherwise see here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-in-collections-and-arrays

Comment: Have you tried with the hash-sign? I'm honest, I'm not sure it works. I mean a collection as key is not what is the most common case :)